# How do I group by identifier and create an array of JSON objects in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table of transactions where I need to group by customerId and create aggregated JSON records in an array.

```
customerId|transactionVal|day
      1234|             2|2019-01-01
      1234|             3|2019-01-04
        14|             1|2019-01-01
```

What I'm looking to do is return something like this:

```
customerId|transactions
      1234|[{'transactionVal': 2, 'day': '2019-01-01'}, {'transactionVal': 3, 'day': '2019-01-04'}]
        14|[{'transactionVal': 1, 'day': '2019-01-01'}]
```

I will need to later iterate through each transaction in the array to calculate % changes in the `transactionVal`.

I searched for a while but could not seem to find something to handle this as the table is quite large > 70mil rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible to use `array_agg` and `json_build_object` like so:

```
ok=# select customer_id, 
     array_agg(json_build_object('thing', thing, 'time', time)) 
     from test group by customer_id;

 customer_id |                                             array_agg                                             
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           2 | {"{\"thing\" : 1, \"time\" : 1}"}
           1 | {"{\"thing\" : 1, \"time\" : 1}",
                "{\"thing\" : 2, \"time\" : 2}",
                "{\"thing\" : 3, \"time\" : 3}"}
(2 rows)

ok=# select * from test;
 customer_id | thing | time 
-------------+-------+------
           1 |     1 |    1
           2 |     1 |    1
           1 |     2 |    2
           1 |     3 |    3
(4 rows)

ok=#
```